# SQL query not working for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I want to update the esal of emp table in my database dynamically but the query is generating error

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

class JdbcEx6
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        Connection ob = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mysql1","root","root123");

        Statement st = ob.createStatement();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the empid");

        int eno = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the increment");

        int inc = sc.nextInt();

        String myquery = "update emp set esal=esal+"+inc+"where eno="+eno;/*error here*/

        int count = st.executeUpdate(myquery);

        ob.close();

        if(count==0)
        System.out.println("Invalid employee Id provided");

        else
        System.out.println("Updated  successfully");


    }
}
```

/*manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'eno=100' at line 1
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)

```
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)

    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3110)

    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:338)

    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:288)

    at JdbcEx6.main(a7.java:18)*/
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post the full error message in your question.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.37-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'eno=100' at line 1
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3110)

Comment: 'in your question' - seems clear enough to me!

Answer (score 2):

As others explain, the problem can be solved by adding a whitespace to the where:

```
String myquery = "update emp set esal=esal+" + inc + " where eno="+eno;
//....................................................^ here
int count = st.executeUpdate(myquery);
```

A better solution would be to use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) rather than plain string concatenation. Here's an example:

```
//query is more readable and easier to understand
//this way is easier to spot problems in the query
//? means a parameter to use in the query
String myquery = "update emp set esal=(esal+?) where eno=?";
//the connection prepares the query
PreparedStatement pstmt = ob.prepareStatement(myquery);
//set the parameters in the PreparedStatement
pstmt.setInt(1, inc);
pstmt.setInt(2, eno);
//execute the statement, which will replace the ? by the parameters
int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String myquery = "update emp set esal=(esal+'"+inc+"') where eno='"+eno"';
```

This works

Answer (score 0):

You are not including spaces correctly in your query. SQL queries in java need spaces correctly just like they do in standard SQL usage.